# Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected error when making a delete fetch in Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, devise

I am using react as my front end, and rails/devise as my backend/auth. Logging in and registering a new user work perfectly fine, however when I try to log out using the /users/sign_out route created by devise (as outlined by the [wiki](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template)) I get the error:

```
Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected
```

My fetch call is as follows:

```
const logout = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out',{
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
        })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(resp => console.log(resp))
}
```

I have made the following changes to my application controller as well.  Not entirely sure if this may be part of the issue:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    include ActionController::MimeResponds
    respond_to :json, :html

    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:login, keys: [:username, :email, :password])
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :email, :password])
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username])
    end

end
```

I have tried using

```
skip_before_action :verify_signed_out_user
```

in my application controller but it raises an error that the method is undefined.

```
ArgumentError (Before process_action callback :verify_signed_out_user has not been defined):
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're not sending the user Authentication token header with your request. You're just sending user as a body args. Usually in logic we set Header like `Authorization: Bearer xyz` to authenticate the user.

When you want a user to sign out, you'll have to send Auth token so that devise can identify the user and sign the user out.

So when devise tries to run `verify_signed_out_user` -> since user is not signed in(no auth token in your case), this problem occurs.

And `verify_signed_out_user` is not a global method like `authenticate_user!`, so you can't call `before_action :verify_signed_out_user` like we usually call `before_action :authenticate_user!` to authenticate the user.

Comment: Okay that's very helpful.  Initially, when I first made my login feature work, the fetch call would return with a response that included a token.  But it doesn't do that anymore.  Does devise come built in with tokens or do you think it's better to utilize other gems for that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your login works? Usually a new user opens website, then the user logins -> your app sends token + user data -> you save at-least your token locally so that you can make requests to API(todo api or articles api) with that token and also you can sign out also. I suggest this article on how to setup API app + it's a good way on how to implement API https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one

Comment: My login is a post request.  I followed a tutorial to allow the login to accept either their username or their email to login.  Upon a successful login fetch call returns the user object and then stores that in local storage.  There isn't any sort of token returned.  I might remake the bakend without using devise.

Comment: Sorry to say, but only saving user data is bad design. In API apps it's kind of standard and best to use auth token with user data, it makes apps more secure. Anyone(users themselves or extensions) can change localstorage. And how do you implement to update the user? Say if you're having a TODO app, how will `current_user` see his todo? You don't want to make TODOs public so any user who sends API request with ID see the todos of other user.

Comment: Coming to your problem as mentioned in the ques, devise doesn't know which user to sign out. You just can't send a DELETE request to sign out. What you're doing is sending the user data as body, so you'll need to re-write devise `sessions#destroy` such that you parse that body, get the username/email from the body, find `@user = User.find_by(username: params["username"])`, then `sign_out @user` with a response. Again this is not the way I recommend.